# Wearing a Tallis for Kiddush Levana

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, tallit-gadol, high-holidays, kiddush-levanah

If people wait until the end of Yom Kippur to say kiddush levana for the month of Tishrei, which I understand to be a prevalent custom, do they keep their talleisim on? Since the tallis is not supposed to be worn at night *except* for maariv on Yom Kippur (see, for example, [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/the-talit-gadol/)), does that mean that people should remove them before going outside? Or is it purely a matter of personal choice?

I ask because, for various reasons, I never get to say kiddush levana b'tzibbur (even motzaei yom kippur), so I actually cannot remember what I used to see happen way back in the days when this was how I said it. And then I saw this beautiful painting:

[image]

Seems to me that everybody in this painting is wearing a tallis, which leads me to suppose that it must (?) be the end of Yom Kippur.

The painting is entitled "[Powrót z synagogi; Kiddusz Lewana - Poświęcenie księżyca](http://cyfrowe.mnw.art.pl/dmuseion/docmetadata?id=4635)", which (according to Google Translate) means something like "Exterior of the Synagogue. Kiddush Levana: Blessing of the Moon". It appears on Wikipedia's [Kiddush Levana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush_levana) page.

The artist's name was Wacław Koniuszko (1854-1900). He was a Polish artist whose artworks are today exhibited in the National Museum in Warsaw. Amongst other things, he was famous for painting the Jews of Kazimierz. I do not know whether or not he, himself, was Jewish, but even if not one might assume that he painted from what he saw.

(1) Is there a custom to don a tallis for kiddush levana on any night of the year *other* than motzaei yom kippur?

(2) Is there a custom to keep the tallis on after davening maariv on motzaei yom kippur for the sake of kiddush levana?

(3) Or, is it all really just a matter of personal preference, and it makes no difference whether or not a person is wearing a tallis at such a time?

[**[Source](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzitzit#cite_ref-37)** for the idea that, normally, a person shouldn't wear a tallis by night.]

Comment: I have seen many people keep their Tallit on during Maariv after Yom Kippur FWIW. (The sources you cite at the bottom for not wearing a Tallit at night say to take it off lest someone think Tzitzit are obligatory at night. Not everyone agrees with that prohibition (eg. Arukh haShulchan) and I truly wonder if this is even a real concern nowadays.)

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/101765 indicates that Chasidei Chabad leave their Talis on (on 11 Tishrei) until after Kiddush Levana, but they take it off their heads and wear a hat instead. So doesn't perfectly match the picture. Perhaps a Lubavitch user would have more info?

Answer (score 3):

In the Mateh Ephraim  סימן תרכד סעיף ד ge says to leave the Tallis and Kittel on for Kiddush Levana.

The Nitei Gavriel brings many more sources in his footnotes פרק סו סעיף טו הערות סעיף כג